# How to play drm protected content in exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, drm, widevine

I implemented exoplayer to play hls and dash contents. But I am struggling to play the dash content with widevine protection. I looked into the example app for Exoplayer, but I did n't get proper idea to implement. Currently I have a dash url and server url. How to easily implement exoplayer to play this content?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for you to test with your content and ensure the playback works is to modify the ExoPlayer sample.

Specifically, if you look at the file where the sample manifest and license servers URL's are defined, you can either add your own example or just replace the URL's in one of the samples with your own.

The sample data is in the file: media.exolist.json: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/assets/media.exolist.json

Assuming your content is using Widevine DRM, you can add or modify one of the entries like this:

```js
  {
    "name": "HD (cenc)",
    "uri": "https://storage.googleapis.com/wvmedia/cenc/h264/tears/tears.mpd",
    "drm_scheme": "widevine",
    "drm_license_uri": "https://proxy.uat.widevine.com/proxy?provider=widevine_test"
  },
```

There are instructions here: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/aeb306a164911aa1491b46c2db4da0d329c83c65/docs/demo-application.md#playing-your-own-content